# IoT hub on private network

Tags: protocols, arduino

I want to make a hub for file sharing in my private network like DC++.

Is there any library which I can use or do I have to develop it from start.

This can be developed for Arduino or Raspberry PI.

Comment: This question is currently too vague, please the read guide about asking good questions (https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and see if you can edit it to add some more details.